# Find all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$ that $x^xy^y=z^z$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was curious about the following diophantine equation $$x^xy^y=z^z$$
The equation seemed to have no positive integer solutions except for when $x$ or $y$ was $1$.

Though I attempted to solve the equation using prime factoring, I was able to proceed no further.

However, since I believe that I saw this question in a book, it is likely that this question is a duplicate or has been solved before. In that case I wish to apologize.

Any progress on the question would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the prime factorization for x,y,z? It may help narrow down the options quite quickly.

Comment: @ChristopherHalverson Yes, actually. Is there an easy solution using prime factorization?

Comment: I am not sure, it seemed a potentially fruitful route but if you have already looked then maybe not.

Comment: @ChristopherHalverson  Has this been asked before?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but if $z=p$ is prime and $x,y>1$ then I think this cannot have solutions. This is because then $x$ and $y$ should necessarily be powers of $p$, so $x^{x}y^{y}=z^{z}$ $\Rightarrow$ $(p^{r})^{p^{r}}(p^{s})^{p^{s}}=p^{p}$ with $r,s\geq{1}$, so this implies $rp^{r}+sp^{s}=p$ which is not possible for $r,s\geq{1}$. I guess this problem is easy for one of those math olympiad kids...